# Apache 2.4 can connect localhost but not IP

Tags: apache-2.4, localhost

Im using Laragon to connect everything together:

```
httpd.conf
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
# Listen 80
# Listen 80
# Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen 80

#
#ServerName www.example.com:80
ServerName :80

#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Not sure where else to edit but my hosts file is empty, no settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
ServerName :80
```

This is wrong. As per [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername):

> Syntax:   ServerName [scheme://]domain-name|ip-address[:port]

E.g. you may omit anything but the domain-name part.

Answer (score 0):

okay something happened

ServerName 47.200.64.76:80

After adding this the IP works but not the DNS.

So can i add this to that section also?

Servername southern.uk.to:80

Technically after the Italians found Florida , landed , infected the indigenious, they all died, and then landed a bit north of that area and called it Venice.

So Venice is named by Italy, so Its not a fake Venice.

**** Could i just add

ServerName please.make.my.server.work.computer:80

Answer (score 0):

---ServerName 47.200.64.76:80
--ServerName southern.uk.to:80
--ServerName 192.168.254.15:80

Added these and seems to connect to 47 IP but through localhost
southern doesnt work at all

We do things differently here in Florida.
lol